# How can I enable the Bluetooth on my Dell Studio 1558?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bluetooth, dell-studio

How can I enable my Dell Studio laptop's 1558 bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that your laptop has a physical hardware switch that would disable all wireless adapters (WiFi and Bluetooth). These types of switches are common on laptops to both save power and make them save to use on airplanes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wireless key on the keyboard, this disables both wireless and bluetooth.
Page 14 of this PDF "Enable or Disable Wireless (Optional)"

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/studio1558/en/SG/sg_en.pdf

.